# Jquery custom event to other document doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Please consider this test:

**Main file:**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          var secondwindow = false;
          $(function() {
              secondwindow = window.open("secondwindow.html");
              $(secondwindow).load(function() {
                  secondwindow.setWindow(window);
              })
              $("#custom").click(function() {
                  $(document).trigger("custom");
              });
          });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button id="click">Click event</button>
      <button id="custom">Custom event</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Second (popup) file:**

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var mainwindow = false;
    
            function setWindow(obj) {
                mainwindow = obj;
                $(mainwindow.document).on("click", function() {
                    $("body").append("<p>Click event from main window</p>");
                });
                $(mainwindow.document).on("custom", function() {
                    $("body").append("<p>Custom event from main window</p>");
                });
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
 </html>
```

My goal is to add a event listener in the second window for custom events in the main window.

What I found, and this test can proves, is that **event listening to other window works for "standard" events like click and not for custom events**.

Can you tell me if this is a jQuery limitation or I'm missing something?

(I'm sorry I could not put that code in a jsfiddle because `window.open` doesn't work very well with jsfiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to take into account the jQuery instance you're using to define your targets and trigger.

```
secondwindow.html -> $(mainwindow.document)
```

is not the same as

```
main.html -> $(document)
```

It needs to be:

```
secondwindow.html -> mainwindow.$(mainwindow.document)
```

Or reverse it:

```
main.html -> secondwindow.$(document)
secondwindow.html -> $(mainwindow.document)
```

jQuery events are managed by jQuery.event object, and this is tied to the instance of jQuery that's being used. You can for example get which events are registered this way:

```
 $.event.global
```

You'll see that the events registered are not only dependent on the selectors themselves, but on the jQuery instance as well. And this is the case for click event as well as custom events.

Comment: mainwindow.$(mainwindow.document).on(...) WORKS! Thank you